# How to specify custom units format in pattern when exporting to excel?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

Using jasper reports I want to generate an excel report that has the option of having units/currencies in the column.

Like column 1: 5,74 **€/h** and column 2: 24,7 **kg**.

In excel I can enter this pattern as  `#.##0,00" €/h"`

However using same pattern in jrxml

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement height="125" style="detail">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="#,##0&quot; €/h&quot;"/>
     </reportElement>
     <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{attributeWithUnit}]]></textFieldExpression>
 </textField>
```

does not work, excel cannot understand it and therefore deformate the whole column or sheet and gives error.

How can/should I format this jasper export for excel to understand how to format it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that to the export engine you actually need to pass `#,##0&quot; €/h&quot;` and not `#,##0" €/h"` and since attributes is parsed it's converted to `#,##0" €/h"`

before you start be sure to enable xls.detect.cell.type

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

and make sure you have a font that can display the Euro symbol correctly.

**With jasper-reports versione 6.4 o above**

Use the CDATA tag

```
<textField>
  <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="30" uuid="a5698aa9-a36e-444d-b590-3340250059a1">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern">
        <![CDATA[#,##0.0&quot; €/h&quot;]]>
    </property>
  </reportElement>
  <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[1235]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

**Versione previous to 6.4**

You need to do escape the `&` so it is correctly `&` when passed to export hence the format string becomes `#,##0.0&amp;quot; €/h&amp;quot;`

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="30" uuid="a5698aa9-a36e-444d-b590-3340250059a1">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="#,##0.0&amp;quot; €/h&amp;quot;"/>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[1236]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Can you maybe add why to use the CDATA instead of putting it in the value part?

Comment: @Nostra I updated post, it will also work with attribute but you need to escape the escape :D, hence export expects `&quote;` which means since it is in attribute needs to be  `&amp;quot;` (hence escaping the &, otherwise it the parsing of the attribute will transform &quote; to " and instead we want &quote; to xlsx)